Removing dots in TOC for LOF and LOT (and only these entries)
Using Remove page numbers of LoF/LoT in TOC i got rid of the Page numbers for LoT and LoF but i do not know how to get rid of the dots.
I am using the scrreprt-documentclass and i'm not sure how to manipulate the table of contents to not show the dots for the \listoftables and \listoffigures. I tried to renew the command

\renewcommand{@dotsep}{10000}

but that doesn't help because i am assuming it's happening inside the \tableofcontents command.


Edit:
I added the dots via toc=chapterentrywithdots in the documentclass.
Below is a (sadly not so minimal) example. I'm not that familiar with the different commands, therefore i'm not sure what is safe to exclude.
I think the main part ist this one from solution B from the answer in Remove page numbers of LoF/LoT in TOC.
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
level=\chaptertocdepth,
indent=0pt,
numwidth=1.5em,
pagenumberformat=\gobblepagenumber
]{chapter}{listchapter}
\newcommand\gobblepagenumber[1]{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
    \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{chapter}{listchapter}{}{\addchapPatchFailed}%
}

Secondly the
toc=chapterentrywithdots

wich i currently commented out to get rid of the dots in every chapter-level-heading.

\documentclass[ 
listof= totoc,
12pt,
titlepage,
bibliography=leveldown,
numbers=noenddot,               % entfernt Punkte nach den Chapter-Nummerierungen
%toc=chapterentrywithdots
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{14}{27}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{12}{27}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}

% Ändern der Überschriften 
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}

%% 1,5 Zeiliger Abstand 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % wofür?

\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin={2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=black,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{bookmark} % wofür?

%%%---blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}   

%% Bibliothek 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, dashed=false,doi=true,isbn=false,url=true,eprint=false]{biblatex}

%% Bibliothek 

%% Seitenzahlen
\ofoot*{\pagemark} %rechts 
\cfoot*{} %mitte nichts
%% Seitenzahlen

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
level=\chaptertocdepth,
indent=0pt,
numwidth=1.5em,
pagenumberformat=\gobblepagenumber
]{chapter}{listchapter}
\newcommand\gobblepagenumber[1]{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
    \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{chapter}{listchapter}{}{\addchapPatchFailed}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{titlepage}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false} %hyperref für diese seite deaktivieren
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\tableofcontents % no page number for lof, lot wanted inside toc


\listoftables
\listoffigures


\cleardoubleoddpage
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}

\chapter*{Kurzzusammenfassung}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Kurzzusammenfassung}

\chapter{Einleitung}

\chapter{Theoretischer Hintergrund}

\section{Fachintegrierte Sprachbildung}
 
\lipsum[6-10] 

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\chapter*{Anhang}
\pagenumbering{Roman} % römische Nummern in groß
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang}

\lipsum

\clearpage
\chapter*{Eigenständigkeitserklärung}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}


Edit2:
I found this code
    \DeclareNewSectionCommand[% siehe KOMA-Script-Anleitung
style=chapter,
level=\chapternumdepth,
%pagestyle=empty,
tocstyle=chapter,
toclevel=\chaptertocdepth,
tocindent:=chapter,
tocnumwidth:=chapter,
toclinefill=\hfill,
tocpagenumberbox=\NoPageNumber,
]{FakeChapter}

in https://texwelt.de/fragen/28713/entfernen-der-chapterentrydots-beim-letzten-chapter but i dont know how to merge it.

Using scrreprt, usually the entries for the LoF, LoT and other chapters are without dots by default. The examples in the linked question also result in entries without those dots. So please show a minimal working example, that shows what you've changed to get these dots, and that can be used to reproduce your problem. Otherwise it can be hard to help you. I can only guess: Read the documentation of options toc and chapterentrydots in the KOMA-Script manual.

@cabohah Thank you for your comment and sorry for not providing an MWE! I've added code in my question.

It is unclear, why you add toc=chapterentrywithdots, if you don't want dots and page numbers for some pages. It is also unclear, why you want some not numbered ToC entries with page number and other not numbered ToC entries without page number. Referencing something in the ToC, that has no page number, makes IMHO no sense and I would not recommend such inconsistency. Instead, IMHO it would be better to use scrbook and \frontmatter and \mainmatter. But if you really want it, please read the documentation of \DeclareTOCStyleEntry and the available TOC styles in chapter 15 of the KOMA-Script documentation. There you will find:

So, if you want the same filler as without toc=chapterentrywithdots, use linefill=\hfill. Because you don't have a page number, you could also use linefill=,raggedpagenumber. I prefer the first:
\documentclass[ 
listof= totoc,
12pt,
titlepage,% NOT NEEDED, BECAUSE IT IS THE DEFAULT
bibliography=leveldown,
numbers=noenddot,               % entfernt Punkte nach den Chapter-Nummerierungen
toc=chapterentrywithdots
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% NOT NEEDED FOR MORE THAN A DECADE, BECAUSE It IS THE DEFAULT
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{14}{27}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{12}{27}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}

% Ändern der Überschriften 
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}

%% 1,5 Zeiliger Abstand 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % wofür? NEEDED; BECAUSE OF USING \ofoot* and \cfoot*

\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin={2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=black,linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{bookmark} % wofür? SEE THE DOCUMENTATION OF THE PACKAGE

%%%---blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}   

%% Bibliothek 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, dashed=false,doi=true,isbn=false,url=true,eprint=false]{biblatex}

%% Bibliothek 

%% Seitenzahlen
\ofoot*{\pagemark} %rechts 
\cfoot*{} %mitte nichts
%% Seitenzahlen

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
level=\chaptertocdepth,
indent=0pt,
numwidth=1.5em,
pagenumberformat=\gobblepagenumber,
linefill=\hfill,% ADDED
]{chapter}{listchapter}
\newcommand\gobblepagenumber[1]{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
    \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{chapter}{listchapter}{}{\addchapPatchFailed}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{titlepage}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false} %hyperref für diese seite deaktivieren
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\tableofcontents % no page number for lof, lot wanted inside toc


\listoftables
\listoffigures


\cleardoubleoddpage
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}

\chapter*{Kurzzusammenfassung}% IF YOU WOULD USE \addchap{Kurzzusammenfassing} ...
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Kurzzusammenfassung}% ... YOU WOULD NOT NEED THIS

\chapter{Einleitung}

\chapter{Theoretischer Hintergrund}

\section{Fachintegrierte Sprachbildung}
 
\lipsum[6-10] 

\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\chapter*{Anhang}% IF YOU WOULD USE \addchap{Anhang} ...
\pagenumbering{Roman} % römische Nummern in groß
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anhang}% ... YOU WOULD NOT NEED THIS.

\lipsum

\clearpage
\chapter*{Eigenständigkeitserklärung}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}



Thank you very much! I really appreciate the effort (you even took the time to comment on my other questions in the code). I am following the formating from my uni, i do not understand either. Again; thank you!
